# Want to remove image path from text file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node html-to-text package. But While I am converting html to text image path is also coming in that file. I want only text version of html. How can I do that? If any other option to convert html to text please let me know.

Comment: SO assume a programming question, but I can't see any code here

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a browser, then let the browser do it for you..

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Ref: [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

for further you want to remove image path you can use regex or replace or simple jquery function and replace the path.

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   $('body img').removeAttr('src')
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

can also try node package https://github.com/werk85/node-html-to-text

Comment: i am using same package node html-to-text, but getting image path in text file

Comment: If you are using browser the before calling html-to-text, try removing all img tags in selected dom and call html-to-text.